# How do I convert a column from a pandas DataFrame from str (scientific notation) to numpy.float64?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6160029/gradStat_mmn.tdf) tab-delimited file into pandas with one caveat:  the last column (mean), must be converted from a string representing a value in scientific notation to a numpy.float64.

So far, I've tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.io.parsers.read_table(fle, converters={'mean': lambda x: np.float64(x)}))
```

but all I get in df['mean'] is `0` and `-0`.

I've also tried importing without the `converters` kwarg, and later casting the column by doing `df['mean'].astype(np.float64)`, with similar results.

What gives?

Comment: They are not zero. At least not here. pandas probably does some formatting for printing `DataFrame` or `Series` so they are shown as `0/-0` (since they are really small). Try printing `df['mean'][0]`.

Comment: @Avaris, I could kiss you!  You are indeed correct!  If you want to submit this as an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not zero. `pandas` probably does some formatting while printing `DataFrame/Series` so they *look like* zero.

By the way, you don't need converters. `read_table` correctly identifies them as `float64`:

```
In [117]: df = pandas.read_table('gradStat_mmn.tdf')

In [118]: df.ix[0:10]
Out[118]:
    Subject Group Local Global  Attn  mean
0         1  DSub     S      S  Attn     0
1         1  DSub     S      S  Dist     0
2         1  DSub     D      S  Attn     0
3         1  DSub     D      S  Dist     0
4         1  DSub     S      D  Attn     0
5         1  DSub     S      D  Dist     0
6         1  DSub     D      D  Attn     0
7         1  DSub     D      D  Dist     0
8         2  ASub     S      S  Attn     0
9         2  ASub     S      S  Dist     0
10        2  ASub     D      S  Attn     0

In [119]: df['mean'].dtype
Out[119]: dtype('float64')

In [120]: df['mean'][0]
Out[120]: 3.2529000000000002e-22
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed with version 0.9 of pandas:

```
In [4]: df = pandas.read_table('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6160029/gradStat_mmn.tdf')

In [5]: df.head()
Out[5]: 
   Subject Group Local Global  Attn          mean
0        1  DSub     S      S  Attn  3.252900e-22
1        1  DSub     S      S  Dist  6.010100e-22
2        1  DSub     D      S  Attn  4.215700e-22
3        1  DSub     D      S  Dist  8.308100e-22
4        1  DSub     S      D  Attn  2.983500e-22
```